# How to specify multiple source files in Makefile.am

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, automake

New to using `autoconf` and `automake`, I am following  [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install) to learn them.

I have a question regarding `Makefile.am` file. For a simple `helloworld` program below `Makefile.am` works:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = helloworld
helloworld_SOURCES = hello.c
```

How do we specify multiple source files (if there are multiple source files required to compile the program) in the third line ?

You can assume all source files are in same directory where the `Makefile.am` is.

Comment: There are much more comprehensive guides to developing an autotools build system, like the [Autotools Mythbuster](https://autotools.io/index.html), which introduces features progressively. The learning curve for the the autotools is very steep, but it's probably the best attempt I've seen that attempts to overcome this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add them to the `hellworld_SOURCES` each file is delimited by a space.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = helloworld
helloworld_SOURCES = hello.c x.c y.c b.c
```

Comment: thanks for help. Also how do i accomodate the `header` file. All my source file use a header file called `header8.h` ?

Comment: well you typically don't compile header files. You don't need to put the header files inside the variable, just the `.c` files.

Comment: @sps If you need to add a dependency, you can use `helloworld_DEPENDENCIES = header8.h` to make the `helloworld` target fail if `header8.h` isn't found.

Comment: @self So will the impacted `*.c` files be recompiled when i make chages to the header file ?  Even if I do not mention it explicitly ? Or should I use `helloworld_DEPENDENCIES = header8.h` as suggested above ?

Comment: @sps no they won't. Try `helloworld_DEPENDENCIES` but I haven't had experience with that.

Comment: @self ok. I think i need to learn the autotool to find out. Untill now I write `Makefile` myself. So i add the `header8.h` as dependency for each `*.o`, this way everytime i modify `header8.h`, impacted `*.c` are recompiled to produce updated `*.o`. But this was not my original question. It was how to store multifle `*.c` filename in `*.SOURCES`, which you answered. Thanks.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune thanks for suggesting the `helloworld_DEPENDENCIES`. I need to learn about the `m4` macros i guess..

Comment: @sps `automake` automatically creates rules to handle dependencies on included header files. You only have to mention the `*.c` files in `_SOURCES` and `automake` and `make` will correctly handle the rest. If that is what you were asking...

Comment: @AndreasBombe Yes, that was what i was asking. Thanks for replying. I just verified that `Makefile` correctly handles the rest..

Answer (score 1):

If you just dont want to provide all file names in `_SOURCES` as below

```
helloworld_SOURCES = hello.c x.c y.c b.c
```

and just want to use `*.c` then you can use it as below in makefile.am

```
helloworld_SOURCES = $(wildcard your_src_dir/*.c)
```